# making nested content take up full width

Tags: html, css, reactjs, video, iframe

```
.video-responsive {
width: 100%,
height: auto
}
```

I have a react card which only has a title and a youtube iframe video embeded inside of it. I want the video to take full width and height without the card's limits interfering with it.

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `vh` and `vw` units, which refer to the current screen width and height, so:

```css
.video-responsive {
    width: 100vw
}
```

You may also need to change the `overflow-y` settings on the containing element.